# Prove that L[f' ' ](s)$ = $sL[f](s)

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, convolution

Can anyone prove this question ?

> Let $f$:$\mathbb{R}$$→$$\mathbb{C}$ be continuous function such that $f$$(0)$ $=$ $0$ and that $f'$ be a piecewise continuous function and absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that

> $L[f'](s)$ $=$ $sL[f](s)$
>
> where $L[f]$ represents the Laplace transform of f

Comment: Did you try integration by parts?

Comment: what would be my u and v values, if I applied the integration by parts method

Comment: Why don't you begin by writing down the definition of the Laplace transform?

Comment: $f(s)= $ $L(ft)(s)$ $$ \int^inf_0 dx $

Comment: And what does the LHS of the identity you're trying to prove look like?

Comment: it looks like the laplace transform differentiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L\{f'(t)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f'(t)dt$

Integrating by parts we have,

$L\{f'(t)\}=e^{-st}f(t)|_0^\infty+s\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$

$L\{f'(t)\}=e^{-s(\infty)}f(\infty)-e^{-s(0)}f(0)+sL\{f(t)\}$

If $e^{-st}$ grows more rapidly than $f(t)$, we have $e^{-st}f(t)\to0$ when $t\to\infty$

$L\{f'(t)\}=sL\{f(t)\}-f(0)$

Since $f(0)=0$, this reduces to

$L\{f'(t)\}=sL\{f(t)\}$

Comment: thanks, do you know of any online resource that deals with this type of question ?

Comment: I think Wiki is sufficient when studying basic Laplace theorem proofs. In the case of this question, wiki goes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Proof_of_the_Laplace_transform_of_a_function.27s_derivative